# Obtain snapshot of .idx file before end of document

Tags: glossaries, indexing, patching

For some trickery concerning cross-references between index and glossary, I would like to obtain a snapshot of the `.idx` file at a certain point of large document (book) - after the main body, but before the glossary, to be precise. There are several possible solutions I have tried, all of them unsuccessfully.

1. open a second `.idx` file (say, `\jobname.idx2`) and patch `\@wrindex` to write to both files. I tried that with `xpatch`'s `\pretocmd`, but it complains:

-

```
analyzing '\@wrindex'
++ control sequence is defined
++ control sequence is a macro
++ control sequence is a macro with parameters
-- nested patching command and parameters in patch
-> the patching command seems to be nested in the
   argument to some other command
-> the patch text seems to contain # characters
-> either avoid nesting or use # characters with
   category code 12 in the patch text
-> simply doubling the # characters will not work
```

Update: Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum,makeidx,xpatch,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\@dblindexfile
\immediate\openout\@dblindexfile=\jobname.dbx

\newcommand{\writedbx}[1]{\protected@write\@dblindexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}}}

\tracingpatches
\AtBeginDocument{\xpretocmd{\@wrindex}{\protected@write\@dblindexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}}}{}{}}
%\xpretocmd{\@wrindex}{\protected@write\@dblindexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}}}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Were the moon landings faked?}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I turns out though that if I do the `xpretocmd` *outside* the `\AtBeginDocument`, it does work:

```
[debug] tracing \pretocmd on input line 13
[debug] analyzing '\@wrindex'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro with parameters
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] == retokenizing macro now
```

And the file does indeed get written, so the patched macro seems to work. I had used the `\AtBeginDocument` to make sure that the patch would be applied to the macro as redefined by `hyperref`, but of course I can make sure of that manually.

So, thanks for the suggestion to make an MWE.

Comment: [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) please

Comment: MWE for what, exactly?

Comment: at least a document that produces the error message that you show would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `#` temporarily of category code 12 as suggested:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum,makeidx,xpatch,hyperref}
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\newwrite\@dblindexfile
\immediate\openout\@dblindexfile=\jobname.dbx

\tracingpatches
\catcode`#=12
\AtBeginDocument{\xpretocmd{\@wrindex}{\protected@write\@dblindexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}}}{}{}}
\catcode`#=6
%\xpretocmd{\@wrindex}{\protected@write\@dblindexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}}}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Were the moon landings faked?}

\lipsum[1]

\index{aaa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you. The effect is the same though as that of just omitting the `\AtBeginDocument`. In both cases, the modifications made by `hyperref` (insertion of `|hyperpage`) are not captured in the patched command. This is not a problem for my purposes. (I was assuming that `hyperref` would throw away my patched command entirely, but it seems that it wraps it instead.) But good to know that one can patch inside `\AtBeginDocument` if necessary.